# WFS layer using isWithinDistance function in SLD?

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to create a cector layer. After querying the layer, if any two of the features are within 300 meters distance, I want to join those two lines and give buffer around the line and display. Is this possible using Style or any other way? Please advise.